# how to use only 1 brand filter for all of the urls?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Actually iam working on one ecommerce site where it has a brand filter.. iam using a select tag (i mean dropdown..) The problem is:

I was able to make it wokr only for 1 url using below script code.. BUT my requirement is: I have to make it to work for all of my urls..

here is my javascript code: (working BUT only for 1 url)

```
<script>

function gotoPage(){
var url = "http://mysite.com/shop/c/laptops/";  //HERE I JUST USED ONE URL for testing
var sel = document.getElementById("brand");
var brand = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text; 
window.location.href = url + "?brand=" + brand;
}

</script>
```

I tried like this too: `var url = <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>;`  in place of `var url = "http://mysite.com/shop/c/laptops/";` BUT still not working...

could anyone pls look into this and provide me a solution..? (BTW, my code is on PHP)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the URL in quotes:

```
var url = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>";
```

Comment: HI ben,

thanks a lot! its working BUT one small thing i need, it shud redirect to msite.com/shop/c/mycategooryname/?brand=brandname , how can i achive this,..? right now, its redirecting to only mysite.com/?brand=brandname